# Difference between T700 carbon frames and 3k carbon frames?

Tags: drone-frame, material

I have heard that iflight's Green Hornet uses T700 carbon instead of 3k carbon. What difference does the new T700 carbon make?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the 300 or 700 is the grade value of carbon fiber and generally, a higher grade means more strength and better performance. The main differences between T300 (3k) carbon and T700 carbon are that T700 carbon has almost 40% more tensile strength than 3k carbon, T700 carbon is slightly denser (and thus heavier for the same volume of carbon), T700 carbon fiber has a higher carbon content and a lower nitrogen content, and T700 carbon fiber is smoother looking while T300 carbon looks more bark-like.

So, overall, T700 carbon is better for making a drone frame because it is significantly stronger with only a small increase in weight.

Comment: T300 is not the same as 3k. 3k refers to the number of filaments in each tow, not the material used: https://www.nj-mkt.com/news/861.html

Answer (score 1):

The "T" stands for [Toray Composite "TORAYCA" carbon fiber](https://www.toraycma.com/products/carbon-fiber/) The frame probably uses T700G, based on the applications Toray has listed for the 2 types of T700.
T700 is also the fiber itself, and not the weave.

Answer (score 0):

T700 and 3K are different indication.
T700 indicate the strength of the frame (higher strength/weight ratio) 3k usually means the number filaments on the surface layer.
You can have a carbon fiber sheet T700 3K

Comment: This was downvoted, but seems to be fundamentally correct: https://www.estcarbon.com/blog/carbon-fiber-what-is-k/ or  https://www.nj-mkt.com/news/861.html or https://www.nextie.com/difference-between-weaves-UD-3K-12K